# How can I run lombok features in my executable jar file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, criteria, lombok

Consider I have a constructor of more that 10 or more args, and I am using it in criteria select query to fetch data.
Now the problem is that I want to remove my constructor as it gives me sonar issues.

So I tried to Lombok dependency, `@AllArgsConstructor` it is working in my IDE,
but when I create the jar file it is not being used by JPA query.

I need help either to make lombok work in my **project.jar** file,

OR

change in select query which does not use constructor,

OR

Any other better way

Comment: Do you have some log?

Comment: u need to use `@NoArgsConstructor` also.. one point lombok annotation generate code in compile time only

Answer (score 2):

Lombok is a compile-time affair. Once your code is compiled (you have class files), lombok shouldn't be there / wouldn't be doing anything. Lombok is not a library in that sense. You don't ship 'javac' with your app either.

If lombok is part of the compilation, then lombok will do its thing. If it's not, then your compiler would generate an error; after all, it wouldn't know what `@AllArgsConstructor` is about. So, if you're not observing any compilation errors, lombok did its thing*.

Secondly, sonar is a linting tool. It's there to help you out. If it is 'telling you off' for writing code where you think it is the best way to do it, then tell sonar to stop complaining about it. It's a tool for you to use; not a prison.

You can use `javap` to check if the all-args constructor is there. If it is (it should be), then your question is actually: How do I make my JPA tooling use that constructor?

*) It is possible, but takes some work, to tell javac to have lombok's classes available, but NOT to run it as an annotation processor. But if you do manage that, then lombok wouldn't have transformed any of your classes. I assume that's not the case, as you need to go out of your way with lots of command line switches to make this happen.

Comment: Well then I think I have stick with the constructors and remove lombok , as the project is already huge. So I agree with you that I can switch off my sonar for constructor.

I have update my question too. - thanks